# Template from template specialization

Tags: c++, templates

Is there a way to get the template from a template specialization? E.g. `std::unordered_map` from a variable of type `std::unordered_map<char, char>` to be passed as a template template parameter.

Minimal example:

```
#include <unordered_map>

template <template <class ...> class t_map>
class A
{
public:
    typedef t_map <int, int> map_type;
};

int main(int argc, char const **argv)
{
    std::unordered_map<char, char> map;

    // decltype yields std::unordered_map<char, char> (as expected).
    typename A<decltype(map)>::map_type map_2;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with the template. In general you can pass around types but not templates. What you may be able to to is to replace the template parameters. Can you give more context?

Comment: I have a couple of classes that (for the sake of polymorphism) take a template template parameter and make a specialization from it. The classes provide a minimal interface to a map-type container. One takes an `std::map`, another an `std::vector` and implements perfect hashing. In order to test a number of specializations of the classes, it would be convenient to write a function that would only take a model container (e.g. `std::map<int, int>`) the template of which would then be passed to my class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of how to create a new type where the template parameter (int) is exchanged (by string):

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

template <typename container, typename newt>
struct replace;

template <typename p1, typename alloc, template<typename,typename >  class containerTemplate, typename newt>
struct replace<containerTemplate<p1,alloc>,newt> {
public:
   typedef containerTemplate<newt,alloc> result;
};

int main() {
 replace<std::vector<int>,std::string>::result vs;
 vs.push_back("a string");
}
```

This way you can pass std::unordered_map as template parameter to your function and replace char by any other type you want. You may need to adjust my example to your needs. But the principle should be clear.

**EDIT:**
More generic for containers, less generic for replacement:

```
template <class Container>
struct replace;

template <template <class...>  class Container, class... Ts>
struct replace<Container<Ts...>> {
   typedef Container<std::string> result;
};
```

Comment: `alloc` should probably be rebound to new type too.

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure, is this what you are looking for, but won't templatized alias declaration fit into your example?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

template <typename T>
using mm = std::map<T, T>;

int main()
{
  mm<int> i;
  mm<char> c;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately not since I would like to pass a specialized variable to a template function and access the template there.